# How to disable contextMenu from QWebEngineView?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qwebengineview

I want to disable the right click menu which appears by default when you create a QWebEngineView.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

webBrowser = QWebEngineView()

#Some line here to delete the contextMenu

webBrowser.load(QUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/"))
webBrowser.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In the doc we can find a class **QWebEngineContextMenuData** which *"provides context data for populating or extending a context menu with actions..."* but nothing to delete in here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To disable the default widgets menu then the contextMenuPolicy must be set to Qt::NoContextMenu:

```py
webBrowser.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.ContextMenuPolicy.NoContextMenu)
```

Comment: Perfect, just what i'm looking for. Thanks' a lot! But in this example to be totally transparent for who read this you need to call Qt.NoContextMenu trough QtCore because i'm not import Qt. I'm disable it by doing  webBrowser.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoContextMenu)

Answer (score 1):

In PyQt6 it is:

> ```
> webbrowser.setContextMenuPolicy(PyQt6.QtCore.Qt.ContextMenuPolicy.NoContextMenu)
> ```